# why do we set path for Servlet-api.jar only. What about Jsp-api.jar

Tags: jsp, servlets

i m new to servlets and Jsps.
I have set CLASSPATH for Servlet-api.jar only. And by doing this i am able to run both servlets and jsps Successfully.

My doubt is what is the reason that JSPs are being run successfully by setting servlet-api.jar and without setting  Jsp-api.jar in the ClASSPATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSPs are translated to Java Servlet code and compiled, so they are in fact nothing else than Servlets. However, you will need the jsp-api.jar once you are using Taglibs and Expression Language.